# Kate text cursor stopped moving through paragraphs ( [Ctrl] + [Up/Down] )

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, vi, kate

I **lost** the function [Ctrl] + [Up/Down] to **move** the text cursor **through paragraphs**, as in **any other text editor**.

I just selected the option to override Kate shortcuts to use [Ctrl] + [V] inside VI to --Block Selection--: Settings → Configure Kate… → Editing → Vi Input Mode: Enabled Override Kate commands on VI mode.

[image]

After that, I lost the function (common to all OS and text editors)  [Ctrl] + [Up/Down]. Even if I turn it off or reset settings to default, **never went back to the original behavior**.

I couldn't find a function to remap the shortcut, and now the [Ctrl] + [Up/Down] is just scrolling down one line, like a mouse scroll.

[image]

How can I **configure** Kate **to** **move** **through paragraphs again**, like every other text processor does?